# Optimizing SQL query that takes too long to bring data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to a query for a healthcare system that counts the number of patients without any assessments (activities patients undergo upon their visit to the clinic). I want to filter out the results for a particular Network, User and Clinic.

This is my query:

```
select count(*) as Qualify from 
UserClinic uc
INNER JOIN Patient p on p.DefaultClinicId = uc.ClinicId and uc.UsersId = 47 and p.NetworkId = 2
where 
p.ActivePatient = 1
and p.deleted = 0
and not exists(select * from PatientToxicologyTesting ptt where ptt.PatientID = p.PatientID)
and not exists(select * from PatientPrescriptionRegistry ppr where ppr.PatientID = p.PatientID)
and not exists(select * from PatientPillCount pc where pc.PatientID = p.PatientID)
and not exists(select * from PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement csa where csa.PatientID = p.PatientID)
and not exists(select * from PatientHealthAssessment mha where mha.PatientID = p.PatientID)
```

UserClinic is a many-to-many relationship table between User and Clinic.
A Patient is linked to a network and clinic.

The above query takes in access of 3 minutes to execute and this time drastically reduces to 1 second if I remove either UserId or NetworkId joining conditions from the query.

Can someone suggest a better way to write this query?

**EDIT**

here's the execution plan of the query

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have indexes on your tables for the column PatientID? It would be helpful if you attach a query plan.

Comment: there's no indexing for the Patient Id column. I have edited my answer to include the execution plan

Comment: Roughly speaking, and without knowing the size of your tables, it seems correct if you would have an index by PatientId in PatientPrescriptionRegistry table and in Patient table.

Comment: You see that green text at the top of the execution plan? That's SQL Server suggesting you to add an index. Right click it, choose `missing index details`, and add that index.

Comment: @JaimeDrq Awesome. The query now executes in fraction of a second.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes I can see that. I don't know why I never thought of checking it out before.

Comment: Each subquery performs a clustered index scan (that means reading all the table data), the bigger a table the slower your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few tips:

1. Do not use 'COUNT(*)' or 'SELECT *' if you are not interested in a specific value you try to select like this. I suggest usage 'COUNT(1)' or 'SELECT 1'
2. Double check that you have indexes on `PatientID` column on tables used in `NOT EXISTS` part. These tables should be checked: `PatientToxicologyTesting, PatientPrescriptionRegistry, PatientPillCount, PatientControlledSubstanceAgreement and PatientHealthAssessment`. You have CLUSTER INDEX SCAN which implies that index is missing or is fragmented. If the index is highly fragmented rebuild/reorganize it.
3. You can create filtering index on `Patient` table to support this query

   `Create Index IX_Patient_Filter_1 ON Patient(NetworkId,DefaultClinicId) WHERE ActivePatient = 1 AND deleted = 0`
4. You can create a supporting index on `UserClinic` table

   `Create Index IX_UserClinic_1 ON UserClinic(UsersId,ClinicId )`

Comment: This helps. Thank you

Comment: about 1: Inside an `exists`, whatever you select is meaningless - you can even do `if exists(select 1/0 from...)` - you will see that the query optimizer ignores the obvious division by zero error. `Count(*)` and `Count(1)` are also treated the same (so count(1/0) will also not raise an error). However, counting a specific column will not count `null` values , while `count(* | const)` will count them, even if there is only one column in the table. [See a demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/UOGEAC90138)